# How do I display a local html file in a UIWebView?

Tags: html, iphone, xcode, uiwebview, google-maps

I have a relatively simple question that I cannot seem to find the answer for. While doing the Google Maps Java API Tutorials, I ran into a problem. I can load an HTML file from the web, but when I try it locally, it just displays the contents of the file instead of running the script.

Here's what works:

```
NSString *url = @"http://code.google.com/apis/maps/documentation/v3/examples/geocoding-simple.html";
NSURLRequest *request = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:url]];
[webView loadRequest:request];
```

I want to store the HTML file locally and run it from the device itself, so I tried:

```
[webView loadRequest:[NSURLRequest requestWithURL:[NSURL fileURLWithPath:[[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"geocoding-simple" ofType:@"html"]isDirectory:NO]]];
```

and it just displayed the contents of the file.

Here is the html file:

```
<html>
<head>
<meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no"/>
<meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8"/>
<title>Google Maps JavaScript API v3 Example: Geocoding Simple</title>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://maps.google.com/maps/api/js?sensor=false"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
  var geocoder;
  var map;
  function initialize() {
    geocoder = new google.maps.Geocoder();
    var latlng = new google.maps.LatLng(-34.397, 150.644);
    var myOptions = {
      zoom: 8,
      center: latlng,
      mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
    }
    map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map_canvas"), myOptions);
  }

  function codeAddress() {
    var address = document.getElementById("address").value;
    if (geocoder) {
      geocoder.geocode( { 'address': address}, function(results, status) {
        if (status == google.maps.GeocoderStatus.OK) {
          map.setCenter(results[0].geometry.location);
          var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
              map: map, 
              position: results[0].geometry.location
          });
        } else {
          alert("Geocode was not successful for the following reason: " + status);
        }
      });
    }
  }
</script>
</head>
<body style="margin:0px; padding:0px;" onload="initialize()">
  <div>
    <input id="address" type="textbox" value="Sydney, NSW">
    <input type="button" value="Geocode" onclick="codeAddress()">

  </div>
<div id="map_canvas" style="width:100%; height:90%"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

What am I doing wrong here?

Thomas

Comment: Hello Thomas, What targets have you cleaned? I have about 12 html pages with javascript, which I would like to show on the phone.

Comment: I cleaned all targets. Build << Clean All Targets

Comment: Thanks, much appriciated. I'll try. I'm doing a free off-line Russian Bible with 1200 pages and with 250 pages for kids. I need to learn more. Spent already a few days and haven't figured out how to make external .js to execute. Found some guidelines on this site, and hope it helps.

Thanks again for your answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK. I cleaned all targets, and it works now...SWEEEET!